# How to reference and register DSOFile.dll in c# project for different platforms 32 and 64?

Tags: c#, com, custom-attributes, regsvr32, dsofile

I am using DSOFile.dll to add custom attributes to windows file system but how reference the dll in my c# project as there two versions of the dll(32 and 64).
Also, How register the correct dll based on the platform either 32 or 46?
I need clear steps to this.

Comment: Hi, Is there any alternatives?

Comment: I want to add Unique Identifier to any type of file

Comment: Any help Hans Passant