Extracting Windows File Properties (Custom Properties) with Powershell for uncommon file types
Is it possible to Set & Get "CUSTOM" file properties with Powershell?
I am not interested in 'Extended' file properties. What I am talking about is the file properties I can add through the Windows File Properties GUI dialog on the "Custom" tab.
On the Custom tab, I can create my own file property name and set its Type ( Text, Date, Number, Yes/No ) and its Value.
My question is quite similar to the ones described here, with the small difference that my files are not Microsoft Office Documents, MP3, JPG's or other common file types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451540/extracting-windows-file-properties-custom-properties-c-sharp 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564356/set-get-custom-file-properties-with-powershell
However, if any solution is given, it usually just read the "Extended Details" and not the Custom Properties. Furthermore, all approaches are quite old (10+ years), so I would be glad about a more modern approach to read and modify the custom properties.
So far I tried in Python (win32api, openpyxl), VBA (GetCustomProperties) and many forums.
Here is an example in Powershell:
$filePath = "C:\mypath\myfile.uncommonfileextension"

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$folder = $shell.Namespace([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($filePath)) 
$file = $folder.ParseName([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($filePath))

for ($i = 0; $i -lt 266; $i++) {
    $propName = $folder.GetDetailsOf($null, $i)  
    $propValue = $folder.GetDetailsOf($file, $i) 

    if ($propValue) {
        Write-Host "$propName = $propValue"
    }
}


Where does that custom tab come from?  I don't have.  Using Win10

Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. The files were generated from the program I work with. So there is no possibility to change this workflow.
However, if you use MS Word or Excel, you can access the custom properties menu via:
File > Info > Properties > Advanced Properties > Custom
This may help, unfortunate I was not able to access the custom made properties via windows explorer (so there ist no extra tab in my case, albeit the properties were set).

Different programs store this type of information differently.  For example MS Word stores these custom attributes inside the word document structure in a file called docProps\custom.xml  The program you work with may have it's own method of storing these attributes so there is probably no one-size-fits-all solution for this.

While this is correct, Windows is able to read this type of information with its explorer (see screenshot). So there must be some standards. Do you have an idea without diving too deep into Windows API?

I assume you are referring to the columns that can be shown in Windows Explorer AFAIR it bases on the Windows Property System https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/property-system-code-samples. However that API is for C/C++ code only.

I believe the last 2 comments on one of the linked questions you provided provide some clues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62564356/set-get-custom-file-properties-with-powershell

Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate. Actually, you both are right, it is only possible with C/C# and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34910936/how-to-reference-and-register-dsofile-dll-in-c-sharp-project-for-different-platf
gave me the hint to work with DSOFile.DLL.
Will have a deeper look.
